# How to initialise SparkContext with custom properties?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jvm, sparkcore

I am learning Spark using the spark-shell.

When running the spark-shell from the terminal, there is already a sparkContext provided by default. I want to add some manual settings to the spark context (like setMaster("local") and setAppName("KVApp")).

When trying to do this from the spark shell as follows:

```
scala> var conf= new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("MyApp")
conf: org.apache.spark.SparkConf = org.apache.spark.SparkConf@55fb92f8

scala> val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

i got the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running 

in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. The currently running SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:82)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
$iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
<init>(<console>:26)
.<init>(<console>:30)
.<clinit>(<console>)
.<init>(<console>:7)
.<clinit>(<console>)
$print(<console>)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
```

Which is obvious as spark context was already created when starting the spark shell.

Is there any way to achieve start spark shell with some customised properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
spark-shell --master "..." --name "..."
```

You can run `spark-shell --help` to see all options available

Answer (score 1):

you can do `spark-shell --conf key=value --name MyShell` much as when you use spark-submit